# Creating pdf with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, amazon-web-services

I need to generate a pdf file and upload it to the AWS upon some action from my controller. I've never done this before with rails, neither created a pdf and then upload it to the aws.

So here is what I'm thinking, how to proceed.

When a action in my controller occurs and it invokes a `method a`, it will invoke the `Job B` which is a delayed job who will call the controller `method c` which has the respond_to and format pdf. And the job will save the .pdf file to the AWS.

The pdf that I'm using needs to be stored on the aws so it can be emailed to a user later. Not sure if this is relevant, just wanted to give more details.

I'm using [prawn gem](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) to generate the pdf

Is there a better way to do this, has anyone done something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rubygems.org/gems/wicked_pdf

"Wicked PDF uses the shell utility wkhtmltopdf to serve a PDF file to a user from HTML. In other words, rather than dealing with a PDF generation DSL of some sort, you simply write an HTML view as you would normally, and let Wicked take care of the hard stuff."

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar using [pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit). Essentially you just define your PDF layout in HTML/CSS, and when a user adds the .pdf suffic to a path, it attempts to generate the PDF. It's nice because you don't have to actually store generated PDF files, but they'll always be available if someone needs them.